# Populating selected value property for CheckedListBox

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I'm using a **CheckedListBox** (System.Windows.Forms.CheckListBox) and running through some code to populate items in the list using a **DataSet**.  My problem is that I can't seem to figure out how to set the **Selected Value** property, or find the right property to set!

Here's my code that successfully adds in the items:

```
for (int i = 0; i < projectsDataSet.tblResources.Rows.Count; i++)
{
   clbResources.Items.Add(projectsDataSet.tblResources.Rows[i]["Description"].ToString());
}
```

There are no useful overloads on the **.Add** method that takes a value parameter and I can't seem to get to a value property of an item.

I guess the bottom line of what I need is the items in the CheckedListBox to display items using one field from my DataSet (like a description) and use another to store that item's value (like a primary key), so would appreciate suggestions to achieve that, thanks!

Comment: How about ListBox.SetSelected Method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.setselected.aspx

Comment: It looks like that only sets which item in the list is selected, I need to set the value (as opposed to the text you can see in the list) of each item in the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make a class for your list box items...

```
public class Thing
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Key + "--" + Value;
    }
}
```

Then add items to your CheckListBox like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < projectsDataSet.tblResources.Rows.Count; i++)
{
   clbResources.Items.Add(new Thing()
   {
       Key = projectsDataSet.tblResources.Rows[i]["Key"].ToString(),
       Value = projectsDataSet.tblResources.Rows[i]["Description"].ToString()
   }, isChecked);
}
```

Comment: I thought it would require something like this, thank you will have a go!

Answer (score 1):

I had had the same issue. Luckily you there is workaround to this.

if the number of items and order of items in ListBox & DataTable is same then you can get the corresponding value as below

```
ListBox.SelectedIndexCollection items = checkedListBox1.SelectedIndices;

            for(int i=0;i<items.Count;i++)
                string selectedValue = projectsDataSet.tblResources.Rows[items[i]]["ValueColumn"].ToString();
```

Comment: Mmmm, I think I understand what you're saying but if something changes in the data source, say someone adds a new record, then it could provide inconsistent results?  Good work-around though thanks!